# Converting columns into class objects

Tags: python, class

I have a class `Asset` that takes a name (should be entered with quotation marks).
This will work fine: `Apple = Asset ('AAPL')`
I want to turn all dataframe columns into Asset objects. Am trying the following code but does not work:

```
for column in df.columns:
    column = Asset (column)
```

I also tried the same thing with df.columns converted into a list of strings.

**Edit**
My goal is to create one object for each column bearing the same name as the column. In this way, the object will possess the content of the column such as price automatically. The class is defined as:

```
class Asset:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.price = df[name]
        self.pct = self.price.pct_change()
```

Comment: It works fine, it just doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Please update your question and explain what you mean by "it does not work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reassigning `columns` just means you are changing the object that the variable references, it does not imply that the original `df.columns` will be updated.

I'd recommend using a list comprehension and assigning the result back:

```
df.columns = [Asset(x) for x in df.columns]
```

---

Based on your edit,

```
asset = [Asset(x) for x in df.columns]
```

Or,

```
asset = {x : Asset(x) for x in df.columns}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I was not clear. Will you please see the edit?

Comment: @st19297 Why won't `assets = [Asset(x) for x in df.columns]` work?

Comment: It will work but gives me a list of objects. How can I have the individual objects in the namespace rather than a list? Sorry, I'm a coding beginner

Comment: @st19297 See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables Short answer is, you can't, and you shouldn't. Use a dictionary instead. See my final edit.